# Como funciona um depurador histórico?

Tags: visual-studio, debug, debug-histórico, intellitrace

Um depurador histórico, ou *historical debugger*, é capaz de coletar dados-chave de uma sessão de depuração, como locals/autos (no caso do [IntelliTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264915.aspx)), exceções e eventos da sessão.

Imagino que algo do tipo seja muito complexo, é como depurar de trás para frente. Corrijam-me se eu estiver errado.

Como funciona um depurador histórico?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não conheço profundamente, mas sei em linhas gerais.

Temos comportamentos e estados. Ou seja, algoritmos e estruturas de dados. Comportamentos são inerentes à aplicação e não mudam. Estados existem durante a execução, e portando eles mudam.

O que o depurador histórico precisa fazer é tirar uma fotografia (*snapshot*) do estado sempre que ele mudar. Com o registro de todas mudanças de estado você pode ir pra frente e para trás.

Pense em projetor de *slides* (se não sabe o que é isto, pense no PowerPoint). Os *slides* são esses estados, você pode ver o próximo ou pode voltar para os anteriores. Obviamente que o próximo pode depender de uma execução de um passo do algoritmo para provocar mudanças de estado, assim como já funciona no *debugger* normal.

Tendo todos registros basta restaurar para o ponto que deseja. Pode inclusive dar um *replay* de todos.

Então nem parece tão complicado assim. Ainda que também não seja tão simples quanto descrever aqui.

Complica um pouco mais com estado externo à memória. Você não pode simplesmente acessar o estado externo novamente, nada garantirá que o resultado será o mesmo. Na verdade tem boa chance de não ser. Então precisa gravar estes estados também. Para restaurá-los complica porque o código tentará acessar o recurso externo, só que se você "voltou na história" tem que injetar o dado gravado no lugar da requisição real.

Pode se tornar impraticável gravar toda mudança de estado. Então isso ocorre seletivamente. Nem todo estado e nem toda mudança é gravada.

Você pode inclusive pegar o arquivo gerado por ele em uma máquina e fazer o *replay* em outra máquina.

Ele ajuda, mas não faz milagres.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: E como obtenho esse arquivo gerado, no caso do VS?

Comment: @Vinícius vou ficar te devendo porque nunca usei (só tem no Enterprise, mas vou ver logo, pq como MVP eu ganhei assinatura completa da MSDN, só estou esperando sair o 2017 mês que vem pra instalar e começar estudar isso.